# Trees Structure - Javascript - Parents?

Tags: javascript

Simply put

I have a tree structure made of objects.

Is it possible to build that tree and add to each object a reference to their parent ?

I know referencing works with objects, but i'm not sure if it would in that case?

I would like to be able to write something like this

```
currentLevel = this.getParent();
```

another exemple would be

```
this.getChildList().addChild({name: test,parent: this})
```

Without having copies and creating multiple tree from the first one.

**2nd question**

How would referencing works with array? Are they considered objects or does it depends on their content?

**3nd question**

Would saving the tree in the browser's cache, via string-JSON serialisation destroy the references?

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: Remember _Objects_ are stored _ByRef_ and not _ByVal_, so you won't create new instances just using an `=`.

Comment: Actually I have my models done, I can create my tree, but before implementing search function and moving functions ( planned to do it with a stack), I want to check on the referencing part?  What code do you need ?

Comment: @PaulS. thats exactly what I want

Comment: Take a look at the Tree component in YUI http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tree/ to get some ideas

Comment: Please... if you want multiple questions, **make them** multiple questions.

Comment: You can't serialise this data structure to _JSON_ by an inbuilt method because it has circular references, you'd have to write your own serealisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this be creating a "TreeNode" class:

```
var TreeNode = (function(){

    //keep track of parent node
    TreeNode.prototype.parent = null;
    //keep track of children
    TreeNode.prototype.children = [];

    function TreeNode(parent) {
        if(parent !== undefined) {
            if(this.setParent(parent)) {
                this.parent.addChild(this);
            }
        }
        //...
    }

    TreeNode.prototype.setParent = function(parent) {
        //add some sort of check to make sure it is a `TreeNode`
        if(parent instanceof TreeNode) {
            this.parent = parent;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    TreeNode.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
        //add some sort of check to make sure it is a `TreeNode`
        if(child instanceof TreeNode) {
            this.children.push(child);
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    TreeNode.prototype.getParent = function(){
        return this.parent;
    }

    TreeNode.prototype.getChildren = function(){
        return this.children;
    }

    return TreeNode;

})();
```

And then you can expand from that.

Example Code:

```
var node_a = new TreeNode();
var node_b = new TreeNode(node_a);
var node_c = new TreeNode(node_a);

console.log(node_a.getParent(), node_c.get_parent()); //null , node_a        
console.log(node_a.getChildren()); //[node_b, node_c]
```

---

This is just a **start**, it needs waaaaaaaaaay more expansion :-)

Comment: _Node_ already exists if you're using a _browser_, it's a bad idea to shadow it.

Comment: with this structure you would create new node by sending the parent has an argument is that it?

Comment: @PaulS. I changed the name to `TreeNode`

Comment: @Neal, my sentence was not clear enough but with the exemple you added, it's exactly what I asked :)  If you add my 2nd question's answer I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Fawar I added the ability for an element to see all of it's children. :-)

Comment: the addChild looks little glitch-y what if I use var node_a = new TreeNode(); node_a.addChild(1); at least a instanceof control might be useful.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL yes... add some checks there... this is just a start of what it could become.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL I added the check.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so there are most likely frameworks out there, but I wrote a quick thing which supports *JSON serialisation* and the reverse (via it's own methods). I took base inspiration from [Neal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal)'s answer. Example

```
var a = new MyTreeNode('a'), // make some nodes
    b = new MyTreeNode('b'),
    c = new MyTreeNode('c');

a.addChild(b).addChild(c); // a parent of b parent of c

c.getParent() === b; // true

var str = a.toJSON(); // "{"nodeName":"a","childNodes":[{"nodeName":"b","childNodes":[{"nodeName":"c","childNodes":[]}]}]}"

MyTreeNode.parseJSON(str); // MyTreeNode (same structure as before)
```

Full code

```
/* MyTreeNode(String nodeName)
Instance Properties
 - nodeName,   String
 - childNodes, Array of MyTreeNodes
 - parentNode, MyTreeNode
Instance Methods
 - addChild(MyTreeNode node),    child MyTreeNode
 - removeChild(MyTreeNode node), child MyTreeNode
 - getParent,                    parent MyTreeNode
 - getChildList,                 Array of MyTreeNodes
 - serialise,                    JSON-safe Object
 - toJSON,                       String
Constructor Methods
 - deserialise(Object serialised), MyTreeNode
 - parseJSON(String JSONString),   MyTreeNode
*/
var MyTreeNode = (function () {
    function MyTreeNode(nodeName) {
        nodeName && (this.nodeName = nodeName);
        this.childNodes = [];
    }

    MyTreeNode.prototype.parentNode = null;
    MyTreeNode.prototype.childNodes = [];
    MyTreeNode.prototype.nodeName = '';

    // getters
    MyTreeNode.prototype.getChildList = function () {
        return this.childNodes = [];
    };
    MyTreeNode.prototype.getParent = function () {
        return this.parentNode;
    };

    // add/remove
    MyTreeNode.prototype.removeChild = function (node) {
        var i = this.childNodes.indexOf(node);
        if (node.parentNode !== this || i == -1)
            throw new ReferenceError('node is not a child of this');
        this.childNodes.splice(i, 1);
        node.parentNode = null;
        return node;
    };
    MyTreeNode.prototype.addChild = function (node) {
        if (node.parentNode) node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        node.parentNode = this;
        this.childNodes.push(node);
        return node;
    };

    // JSON
    MyTreeNode.prototype.serialise = function () {
        var o = {
            nodeName: this.nodeName,
            childNodes: []
        }, i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            o.childNodes.push(this.childNodes[i].serialise());
        }
        return o;
    };
    MyTreeNode.prototype.toJSON = function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this.serialise());
    };
    MyTreeNode.deserialise = function (o) {
        var p = new MyTreeNode(o.nodeName), i;
        for (i = 0; i < o.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            p.addChild(MyTreeNode.deserialise(o.childNodes[i]));
        }
        return p;
    };
    MyTreeNode.parseJSON = function (str) {
        var o = JSON.parse(str);
        return MyTreeNode.deserialise(o);
    };
    return MyTreeNode;
}());
```

Comment: It seems as if you expanded on my code :-P looks good though :-D

Comment: @Neal yup, I wanted to add loads of things way more than a comment could enable

Comment: Well mainly the ability to go to/from JSON :P

Answer (score 1):

You could traverse your object and add parent properties to every subobject:

```
function addParents(obj) {
    var name;
    for (name in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[name] === "object") {
            addParents(obj[name]);
            obj[name].parent = obj;
        }
    }
}

var obj = {
    g: {
        k: [
            {
                r : 1
            },
            {
                r : 1
            }
        ],
        j: {
            h: 1
        }
    }
};

addParents(obj);

console.log(obj.g.parent === obj); //true
console.log(obj.g.k.parent === obj.g); //true
console.log(obj.g.k[1].parent === obj.g.k); //true
console.log(obj.g.j.parent === obj.g); //true
```

And if you want to add objects later on, you could use something like this:

```
function addChild(obj, child, name){
    obj[name] = child;
    child.parent = obj;
}

addChild(obj.g, {t:1}, "xy");

console.log(obj.g.xy.parent === obj.g); //true
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3McjE/1/)**